# Complex equation of letting $w$ as a root of the equation

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

> Let $w$ be a root of the Complex equation $z^8=1$. Find the value(s) of $$(w^{-3}+w^{-2}+w^{-1}+1+w^1+w^2+w^3+w^4)^\frac{1}{2}$$

May I ask how to approach this kind of question ?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I suggest first finding some of the $8$ solutions of $z^8=1$ and substitute them in the expression.

Comment: The present format of this Question is that of a "pass through exercise", i.e. you were asked something to reinforce or test your learning of complex roots, and you've simply passed it along verbatim to your Readers.  We cannot guess at what you've studied that led up to this exercise, why it is challenging or interesting for you, or what research or approaches you've already tried.  Voting to close for lack of context.